# how do i set background size all mobile support

Tags: css

I have created email template now all mobile device is working `background-size:100% 100%` but not working only Samsungv10 mobile could you please let me know what issue and how do i solve this.

My css:

```
background:url("znp.png"):
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Comment: Are you using a supported email client? https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-size/

Answer (score 0):

Use background `cover` property. will cover entire screen area.

```
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: if i used background-size:cover; code not comes responsive could you please my url http://magento.unaux.com/nt/?i=1

Comment: I saw you are creating newsletter and background size will not be compatible with major all the email client so i will suggest you you use the entire image only. check this out --- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **contain** property, this is fit inside the div:

```
background-size: contain;
```